# Linq2sql -> how to group by a lower level entity and concatenate upper level data?

Tags: c#, linq-to-sql

I have tool that should show data in linq2sql PagedList with some aggregation.

My Entities:

```
User -> UserSubSkill(with a Level info from 1 to 6) -> SubSkill -> Skill
```

So there are 10 Skills defined. Every skill has a lot of subskills. 
The users have subskills assigned with a proficiency level from 1 beginner to 6 expert.

My search is filterind for a specific skillset and some level of expertise.

I want to show the user with the skill where an assigned subskill exists with one of the given proficiency levels.

The display shoud be

```
User  -  Skill  -  Concatenated list of Subskills of this skill.
```

Example:

```
John Doe   -   Programming   -  Tool A (3), Tool B(5) 
John Doe   -   Database      -  Tool DB_1 (5), Tool DB_2 (2)
Jane Dee   -   Programming   -  Tool A (1)
```

I am struggeling at the moment with the Linq2SQL in c#.

At the moment I have something like:

```
ctx.UserSubSkill.Include(SubSkill).Include(Subskill.Skill).Include(User).Where(uss => uss.Level > 0 && subSkillsToSearch.Any(sts => sts == uss.SubSkillId))
```

Where subSkillToSearch is a list of all subskills of the skills that the query is looking for.

Answer (score 0):

I find it easier to use query syntax when creating more complex statements. I believe you are looking for something like this:

```
var query =
   from u in ctx.Users
   from uss in u.UserSubSkills
   where uss.Level > 0
   where subSkillsToSearch.Contains(uss.SubSkillId)
   group uss by new 
   { 
     u.ID, 
     UserName = u.Name, 
     SkillName = uss.SubSkill.Skill.Name 
   } into uss
   select new
   {
     User = uss.Key.UserName,
     Skill = uss.Key.SkillName,
     SubSkillAndLearningList = uss.Select(x => x.SubSkill.Name + " (" + x.Level + ")")
                                  .ToList()
   };
```